# Modify permission of files containing a given string

Tags: regex, linux, bash

```
result=$(grep -r "find this string" / | 2> /dev/null) #don't care about permission denied errors, so ditch them.
#regex=':(.+)' #matches after the filename (ie. ':String to match')
for line in $result 
do
    #need to preform regex on result
    echo "line = $line..."
    chown root:root $line
    chmod 700 $line
done
```

I got an assignment asking for a shell script which will find a string in all files in an entire Linux filesystem (as in `/`) and then will change the permissions of those files to only be usable by root.

The only way I can think to do this is with grep and regex (regex to pull out the `:string` part of the result) but I can't figure out how to do regex on a bash variable.

In Perl it would be something like `$line =~ s/$regex//g` (sorry, my Perl is a bit rusty too).

Simpler solutions are welcome too. I'm probably over complicating :)

Comment: You want to replace something in `result` using a regex?

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused. Is it "find files containing a string and change their permissions", or "modify contents of certain files"? If it is both, the provided answers can be neatly combined ;)

Comment: I'm really confused too, but I agree with you @BenjaminW.

Comment: 'find files containing a string' not 'modify contents of files'- your answer does the trick Benjamin

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single line command I put together that will "find a string in all files in an entire Linux filesystem (as in /) and then will change the permissions of those files to only be usable (in this case specifically to read/write) by root."

```
find /. -type f -exec grep -rl 'textyouarelookingfor' {} \; -exec chmod 600 {} \; -exec chown root:root  {} \; > /dev/null 2>&1
```

It finds files and searches for the specified text and then changes the permission and the owner/group to root.

I can't speak to the beauty or the speed of it, but I know it works like a charm on files in sub-directories!  I wouldn't recommend running it on your machine with searching for text like '' for example.  It could mess your whole machine up by changing permission to things you don't expect...

Put the single line in a shell script and you are done.

Comment: That's the solution I was trying to get to at first, but gave up because I wasn't aware that the return value of `-exec` can be used as filter for `find`! Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

To have grep return just file names, you can use

```
grep -rl 'find this string' /
```

Instead of saving this to a variable and then relying on word splitting to loop over it, we can feed it directly into a loop:

```
while IFS= read -r fname; do
    chown root:root "$fname"
    chmod 700 "$fname"
done < <(grep -rl 'find this string' /)
```

The `<(...)` construct is called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). It basically makes the output of a command behave like a file (a named pipe, to be precise).

Notice that what you're trying returns the matched lines, and setting permissions on those doesn't make much sense.

This solution is able to deal with file names containing spaces. To extend it to be able to deal with file names containing newlines, we can use the `-Z` option of grep, which does this:

> Output a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of the character that normally  follows  a  file  name.

The loop changes as follows:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' fname; do
    echo chown root:root "$fname"
    echo chmod 700 "$fname"
done < <(grep -rlZ 'find this string' /)
```

where `-d $'\0'` tells `read` that input is separated by zero bytes instead of newlines.

Comment: Can you explain the "< <" on the last line? (its clear that its redirecting to fname but I wish to understand the rule, rather than assuming)

Comment: @JohnathonBuffalo I've added a short explanation with a link to the manual. More info: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

Comment: Ah, and in general, to loop over a file, you'd do `while read line; do ... done; < filename` where `<` is just redirection. So `< <(...)` is redirecting a process substitution.

Comment: process substitution seems not to work with 'sh', even with a shebang line. (works fine with bash)
Is there a way to make it work with 'sh script.sh'? (mostly educational curiosity asking)

Comment: @JohnathonBuffalo The Bourne Shell does [not have process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell.html). In this case, I guess you can also pipe grep to the `while` loop: `grep -rlZ 'string' | while ...`, but be aware of potential pitfalls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024